# Using SQL to get the previous rows data

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a requirement where I need to get data from the previous row to use in a calculation to give a status to the current row. It's a history table. The previous row will let me know if a data has changed in a date field.

I've looked up using cursors and it seems a little complicated. Is this the best way to go?

I've also tried to assgin a value to a new field...

newField =(Select field1 from Table1 where "previous row") previous row is where I seem to get stuck. I can't figure out how to select the row beneath the current row.

I'm using SQL Server 2005

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "previous" how?? Based on what critiera, what sort order, what `ORDER BY` statement??? SQL Server doesn't have an "order" per se - you only get order when you specify an `ORDER BY` clause....

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure. It not simple in SQL Server 2005, but you can achieve it by using Row_Number and Self Join .....

Comment: You are stuck because you are trying to get the row beneath the current row.  Everyone knows previous rows are *above* the current row.

Comment: *I've looked up using cursors and it seems a little complicated. Is this the best way to go?* almost always no

Comment: How do you define "previous row"?  Are you asking for the row whose primary key is the next highest value, or is there a date field that tracks the order of rows.  You'll need to provide a little more info.

Comment: The table is sorted by Project Number, then the datechanged. I need to be able to tell if the previous change is the Original value or if it is a change to the original entry. I also need to count all of the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- Test data
declare @T table (ProjectNumber int, DateChanged datetime, Value int)
insert into @T 
  select 1, '2001-01-01', 1 union all
  select 1, '2001-01-02', 1 union all
  select 1, '2001-01-03', 3 union all
  select 1, '2001-01-04', 3 union all
  select 1, '2001-01-05', 4 union all
  select 2, '2001-01-01', 1 union all
  select 2, '2001-01-02', 2

-- Get CurrentValue and PreviousValue with a Changed column
;with cte as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by ProjectNumber order by DateChanged) as rn
  from @T
)
select
  C.ProjectNumber,
  C.Value as CurrentValue,
  P.Value as PreviousValue,
  case C.Value when P.Value then 0 else 1 end as Changed
from cte as C
  inner join cte as P
    on C.ProjectNumber = P.ProjectNumber and
       C.rn = P.rn + 1

-- Count the number of changes per project  
;with cte as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by ProjectNumber order by DateChanged) as rn
  from @T
)
select
  C.ProjectNumber,
  sum(case C.Value when P.Value then 0 else 1 end) as ChangeCount
from cte as C
  inner join cte as P
    on C.ProjectNumber = P.ProjectNumber and
       C.rn = P.rn + 1
group by C.ProjectNumber
```

Comment: Wow, this looks promising. Putitng it in place now. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I put this in place and it worked great!!! 

I see the skills/concepts I was missing. 

The CTE works great. I've used Temp tables and tried a view but the CTE is much easier.  The CTE allows you to connect the table to itself which is very valuable. ANd combined with the row_numbers works great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on what tells you a row is a "Previous Row".  however, a self join should do what you want:

```
select *
from Table1 this
  join Table2 prev on this.incrementalID = prev.incrementalID+1
```

Comment: Each row doesn't have a unique ID. is incrementalID something that is built into the table?

Comment: Also the data I'm working with  is a subset of the full table so if there was an incremental ID the subset may not be in sequential order.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
   Id            INT NOT NULL,
   ChangeDate    DATETIME NOT NULL,
   .
   .
   .
)
```

The following query will return the previous record for any record from `MyTable`.

```
SELECT tbl.Id,
       tbl.ChangeDate,
       hist.Id,
       hist.ChangeDate
  FROM MyTable tbl 
       INNER JOIN MyTable hist
        ON hist.Id = tbl.Id 
       AND hiost.ChangeDate = (SELECT MAX(ChangeDate) 
                                 FROM MyTable sub 
                                WHERE sub.Id = tbl.Id AND sub.ChangeDate < tbl.ChangeDate)
```